# While running in Localhost it's working but after deployed in Azure getting Error

Tags: c#, azure, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

While running in Localhost it's working but after deployed in Azure getting Error Please look at Below Screen Shot

**Error is:** There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

[image]

Comment: Please take a moment to read this "How to ask questions on StackOverflow": https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

According to the exception, it seems that you don't closed the DataReader correctly.

Try to avoid using readers like this:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection string"))
{

    connection.Open();

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM SomeTable", connection))
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //do something
                }
            }
        } // reader closed and disposed up here

    } // command disposed here

} //connection closed and disposed here
```

For more information to solve this, you could refer to this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/616154/There-is-already-an-open-DataReader-associated-wit).